# Glide update Cannot detect VCS

Tags: go, glide-golang

Trying to set up the go project using `Glide`. I have been finding the error `Cannot detect VCS` when I ran the command `glide up -v`.

## Errors:

```
[ERROR] Error looking for project/base: Cannot detect VCS
[INFO]  --> Fetching project/form
[WARN]  Unable to checkout project/form
[ERROR] Error looking for project/form: Cannot detect VCS
[INFO]  --> Fetching project/api
[WARN]  Unable to checkout project/api
[ERROR] Error looking for project/api/request: Cannot detect VCS
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/go-openapi/analysis
```

Answer (score 2):

I saw something similar using `glide update` using Glide 0.13.2, and Go versions 1.10.6 and 1.11.5.

Using the more detailed `glide --debug update`, I found a wee bit more detail: -

```
[DEBUG] ImportDir error on /Users/hayd/.glide/cache/src/https-crypto-tls: cannot find package "." in:
    /Users/hayd/.glide/cache/src/https-crypto-tls
```

*BUT* this did lead me to look at my Git source folder -  `$GOPATH/src` - which, amongst other things had this: -

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 hayd  staff   96 29 Mar 19:31 crypto
```

which was a directory containing a sinmgle empty subdirectory: -

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 hayd  staff   64 29 Mar 19:33 tls
```

So this kinda tied up with the symptom shown up in the `--debug` trace i.e. `cannot find package "."` even though it was in a completely different place.

Once I did `rm -Rf $GOPATH/src/crypto`, the `glide update` worked a treat.

I'd previously gone down a rabbit hole with `glide clear-cache` and `glide mirror`, both of which were poisson rouge.

Hope this helps others in the same situation :-)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when I had a dependency with the `https://` at the start. I simply removed that so it looked like `github.com/dependency` and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I myself experienced this issue and would like to add that here for reference.

```
Go Version : go version go1.13.4 darwin/amd64

[DEBUG] Trying to open github.com/BurntSushi/toml (/Users/folder/.glide/cache/src/https-github.com-BurntSushi-toml)
[DEBUG] Package github.com/BurntSushi/toml imports io/fs
[DEBUG] Missing io/fs. Trying to resolve.
[INFO]  --> Fetching io/fs
[WARN]  Unable to checkout io/fs
[ERROR] Error looking for io/fs: Cannot detect VCS
```

I was facing the error shown above while running `glide --debug up` command. Realising that the issue lies with ***toml*** dependency I manually deleted the folder `https-github.com-BurntSushi-toml` from `.cache` folder.

Then again I ran the command `glide --debug up`. Again I was faced with the same error. It took me a while to realise that `io/fs` was a new addition in go 1.16 version.

The issue in this case was due to update of the package to the latest version. The latest version of the [*toml*](https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml/) package needed a `go version 1.16` while I was on `version 1.13`. So then I needed to revert to the older version of *toml* which I was using earlier in glide.lock(I had added some dependencies and wanted to run update on them , older version of *toml* package was good enough for me).

The error `Cannot detect VCS` is very general error and  you might need to look at the error to understand what is going on and fix accordingly.